# Can Linux syslogd log non-English messages?

Tags: syslog

I am setting up a logging infrastructure using syslog daemon on my Linux server. I have few clients both Windows and non-Windows that I am planning on configuring to forward logs as syslogs to my Linux server. Some of my client machines log in foreign language. Therefore, how do I forward such non-English logs as syslogs over to my Linux server? Do I need to setup any special encoding on my server and in my client? Is this the right approach or is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current syslogd is 8-bit clean, so encode for UTF-8 and you will be fine. Just make sure that the consoles or anything that uses the actual logs knows that the data is UTF-8 encoded so that it can be displayed properly later.